# spring batch+spring boot+java config+test cases

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-test

spring batch+spring boot+java config+test cases

I have followed the below example and my use case matches this, I have implemented the project with similar setup everything works fine.

I am struck with writing test case , could someone s=throw some light or show me the approach for writing he unit test cases..

**spring batch+spring boot+java config+test cases**

```
     //@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JobConfiguration.class,})
@ComponentScan("uk.gov.iebr.batch.processor")
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = IEBRRecommendInterventionsApplication.class)


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Import(IntegrationTestConfiguration.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class BatchJobRecommendTest {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;

    @Test
    public void testJob() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();
        Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, jobExecution.getStepExecutions().size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testStep() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("step1");
        Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.COMPLETED, jobExecution.getExitStatus());
    }




I wrote this test case but , getting Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: public javax.sql.DataSource uk.gov.iebr.batch.configuration.JobConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.
```

PLease show some directiosn or links where i can draw reference or github code base where something similair test cases are implemented ...

Answer (score 0):

```
I wrote this test case but , getting Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
```

BeanCreationException came when there is a problem in JPA Query or an error in class.

```
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
```

In your case, it shows some errors in Autowired. Check you Query and Class that Annotated with @Component, @Service.

Answer (score 0):

This is up and running for me:

```
import com.mastercard.installments.offers.processor.common.JobConstants;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.batch.core.*;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.batch.test.context.SpringBatchTest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBatchTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class JobLauncherCIT {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Test
    public void testJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob(new JobParameters(JobHelper.getJobParameters()));
        Collection<StepExecution> stepExecutions = jobExecution.getStepExecutions();

        List<StepExecution> arrStepExecution = new ArrayList<>(stepExecutions);
        StepExecution stepExecution = arrStepExecution.get(1);
        if (stepExecution != null) {
            assertEquals(3, stepExecution.getReadCount());
            assertEquals(3, stepExecution.getWriteCount());
        }

        JobInstance jobInstance = jobExecution.getJobInstance();
        assertEquals("fetchConsumerInfoJob", jobInstance.getJobName());

        ExitStatus jobExitStatus = jobExecution.getExitStatus();
        assertEquals(JobConstants.COMPLETED, jobExitStatus.getExitCode());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data source bean could not be created. You need to check that:

1. The test database connection details are in the test property file.
2. The pom.xml file has all the required libraries.
3. You have `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` annotation in the class level.

If those are correct, the data source bean should be created in the application context.

If you need sample source code, let me know and I will arrange it without any issue.